# Find Duplicates using Rank Over Partition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

The following SQL works in identifying unique phones when there is a disparity in LastDate.
But if duplicate phones have the exact same LastDate it does not work.

Any ideas will be appreciate it.

```
SELECT * FROM
 (
  SELECT  ID, Phone, [LastDate]
  ,RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Phone ORDER BY [LastDate]) AS 'RANK',                          
            COUNT(Phone) OVER (PARTITION BY  Phone) AS 'MAXCOUNT'
              FROM MyTable          
              WHERE Groupid = 5
              ) a
              WHERE [RANK] = [MAXCOUNT]
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Change the `RANK` for `ROW_NUMBER`.

```
SELECT * 
FROM  (   SELECT    ID, Phone, [LastDate],
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Phone ORDER BY [LastDate]) AS 'RANK',
                    COUNT(Phone) OVER (PARTITION BY  Phone) AS 'MAXCOUNT'
          FROM MyTable
          WHERE Groupid = 5) a 
WHERE [RANK] = [MAXCOUNT]
```

Comment: thanks! helped me with the same problem, only more complex. I needed more columns in PARTITION BY