# How to set a custom 'rank' order for MAX function in query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a dataset with duplicates that contains a 'status' integer field. I was wondering if there is some way to set the MAX() aggregate function to 'set' certain values to be lower priority.

What I'm ultimately after is to run a query on this dataset to group the duplicates and pick the one with the 'max' status value that isn't '6' but return 6 if it is the value and there are no duplicate for this record.

Is using MAX the best way to go about this or is there a better way?

Answer (score 2):

```
select coalesce(max(case when id = 6 then null else id end), max(id))
from (select 6 id union all select 2) a
```

I agree with Dems' suggestion for improvement, thank you @Dems

```
select coalesce(max(nullif(id, 6)), max(id))
from (select 6 id union all select 2) a
```

if 'id' is never null, max(id) can be replaced with 6

Comment: `NULLIF(id, 6)`?  And the 2nd parameter of the `COALESCE` could just be `6` if the OP were to confirm that the `id` can never be `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @T table
(
  Grp int,
  Val int
)

insert into @T values
(2, 1),
(2, 2),
(2, 6),
(6, 6),
(7, 2),
(7, 6),
(7, 7)

select Val
from 
  (
    select Val,
           row_number() over(partition by Grp 
                             order by case when Val = 6 
                                        then 1 
                                        else 0 
                                      end, Val desc) as rn
    from @T 
  ) as T
where T.rn = 1
```

Result:

```
Val
-----------
2
6
7
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server you may want to explore the rank functions.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176102.aspx

[Find Duplicates using Rank Over Partition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7569533/find-duplicates-using-rank-over-partition)